# Does pinch zoom trigger media queries?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, pinchzoom

I've been developing a website on my local machine that has a fixed nav menu at the top. When a browser zooms in, I use media queries to compress the space between objects in the header so all objects fit on screen, and this works well on desktop.

However, I've noticed when testing on a mobile device (Android Galaxy S3) that these media queries are not triggered on pinch zoom, resulting in the icons expanding past the limits of the mobile viewport.

I can't find good documentation of this behavior online. I've seen it mentioned sporadically that this is designed behavior, and pinch zoom is like a 'magnifying glass' that should not activate media queries. I'm considering disabling the nav menu on mobile entirely. Is there a native way to deal with this problem, or will this require a javascript solution?

Here are two pictures. The first is the nav menu at no zoom, the second is the nav menu pinch zoomed on a mobile device.

[image: nav menu with no zoom]

[image: nav menu acting badly with pinch zoom]

Below are the two media queries I'm currently using. Note that I am using the meta viewport tag to set the content width as well; I can't think of anything else that might influence this behavior.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 74em){...}
@media screen and (max-width: 47em){...}
```

I have tried px measurements as well.

Let me know if any more information is required. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is in the meta viewport tag?

Answer (score 0):

I was oscillating between fixing the viewport to the device width and fixing it to an absolute width, as well as testing between browsers. Setting the meta viewport tag to device-width works on some browsers, but not all, and it appears mobile has [historically poor support](http://dbushell.com/2013/09/10/css-fixed-positioning-and-mobile-zoom/) for fixed headers. I ultimately opted to simply disable the header on certain devices; I think any other solution would demand using javascript and probably yield a pretty poor performance on mobile devices.

As well, setting the viewport to device-width may compress the body of an HTML page set to 100% height to less than the device height, which is a problem if you're working with a footer. I ultimately solved this by padding out the body with extra space depending on the aspect ratio.

After dealing with this problem I'd recommend avoiding fixed items on mobile devices, unless you specifically target a userAgent. In general mobile devices are too dynamic in size, and using fixed headers seem to be a bit more trouble then they're worth.